# How correctly implement a call of a modal window in an extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension, and I need that by clicking on the button on the keyboard, say `L` was called modal window with some kind of inscription (a simple alert will not work, because the window needs to be stylized). But I encountered a problem that I do not understand exactly how to do it: whether it is necessary to do separate files with `html` and `css` or simply by clicking on the button, it's just always to create `html` markup with `js`. Who has already worked with this tell me how this happens? The function of calling the window is in `content-script.js`.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown',changer,false);
function changer(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 76 ){
      document.getElementById("modal_form").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#modal_form {
 width: 300px; 
 height: 300px; 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 3px #000 solid;
 position: fixed;
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="modal_form"> 
      <span>Some text in modal window</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: You can insert any standard DOM elements into the page, see also [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)

Comment: @wOxxOm okay, but i do not ask for some solution, i'm asking for way of realisation of my task. So i need just some example of modal window in extensions. I know how create modal window, but not in extensions

Comment: The content script can do anything a normal page script can because it has direct access to the page DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, but modal window is a creating new `html` and `css` code. In `content.js` i can insert some `html` and `css` in DOM. But i can't create new `html` on some random page

Comment: Why can't you create it? How do you do it? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @wOxxOm okay, i added some code for creating modal window if i need create it for my site. But how i can create this window for another random site(i can't create new DOM  on some site)

Comment: Why can't you create DOM on some site? Content scripts can do it. Simply use document.createElement and any other standard DOM methods.

Comment: @wOxxOm it doesn't work, for some reasons. That's why i asking for some example of modal window in extension

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem if you operating [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) for creating modal.

Main benefits of such approach – style and DOM isolation. 

Please note, that you must use `shadowRoot` as a root for DOM subtree (instead of `document`).

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // create a host for Shadow DOM Root
    const div = document.createElement('div'); 

    // create shadow root 
    const shadowRoot = div.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    // insert a modal window into the shadow DOM 
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<h1 id="modal_form" style="display:none; border: 2px solid red;">Modal window</h1>';

    // put the host element inside original DOM 
    document.body.appendChild(div);


    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
         if(e.keyCode === 76 ){ // "l" - key

            // show the modal
            // it is "shadowRoot" here instead of "document"
            shadowRoot.querySelector('#modal_form').style.display = "block";
          }
    });
});
```